# Is there any way we can log only header sizes of requests/responses in the nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are getting the error in nginx like,  *270983 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream*. Many links suggested to increase the proxy and fastcgi buffer sizes. But how can I decide what should be the values? We can log the requests & response sizes using **log_format perf '$remote_addr $status - $request_length $bytes_sent'**. But I need to know only header size only so I can increase the buffer sizes accordingly.

Comment: You can [use `curl`](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx) to calculate the header size of problematic resources.